Null distribution for 1 vs 2 source detection likelihood ratio test
I am wanting to construct a likelihood ratio test something like the following:
I have $N$ observations, let's say in 2D. Each observation comes with its own uncertainty estimate, i.e. from its own measurement process. But they are all obstensibly observations of the same thing, a "source". Assume the measurement processes can be well described by multivariate normal distributions, so that the PDF for the $i$th measurement process is
$$
P(x_i|\mu, \Sigma_i) = \mathcal{N}(x_i|\mu, \Sigma_i)
$$
The PDF for all $N$ observations is then (assuming independence)
$$
P_1(x_1,...,x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N\mathcal{N}(x_i|\mu, \Sigma_i)
$$
i.e. the expected value $\mu$ is the same for all observations since the source is assumed to be the same, but they have difference covariances $\Sigma_i$.
Ok great. This is our null hypothesis. Now let us consider an alternate hypothesis: there are actually two sources being observed, but we don't know which observations correspond to which source. The assignment isn't random, there is no chance of a measurement process for one source accidentally obtaining measurements of the other source. It's just that we don't know whether there are two sources or which observations come from which source.
My intuition is just to construct the likelihood with two source location parameters, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, and stick them in the likelihood. We don't know which observation should be assigned to which source, but anticipating that we are going to do some kind of likelihood ratio test where we maximise over the free parameters, let's just maximise over all possible assignments. We effectively have a set of alternate hypotheses such as
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_2(x_1,...,x_N) &= P(x_1,...,x_M)P(x_{M+1},...,x_N) \\
 &= \prod_{i=1}^M\mathcal{N}(x_i|\mu_1, \Sigma_i) \prod_{j=M+1}^N\mathcal{N}(x_j|\mu_2, \Sigma_j)
\end{aligned}
$$
where we are then going to just maximise over all permutations of this.
I would like then to construct a likelihood ratio test to try and exclude the one-source null hypothesis in favour of a two-source alternative.
$$
\Lambda = -2 \log \frac{ \hat{P}_1 }{ \hat{P}_2 }
$$
where $\hat{P}_1$ indicates maximisation over the $\mu$ free parameter in the one-source case, and $\hat{P}_2$ indicates maximisation over $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ for all possible
assignments of observations to sources. The parameter maximisation is pretty easy because
the MLEs for $\mu$, $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ are analytically computable; the maximisation over all permutations of assignments just takes brute force computing them all I think.
I'd like to hope that this is vaguely chi-square distributed under the single-source null hypothesis, and indeed from simulations it looks kinda chi-square with $~N$ DOF, but its a bit off, the DOF are a little less than $N$ and the shape is a bit wrong.
So, now my question. Is it obvious to anyone what the null distribution is in this situation, or how to alter it to get an easy analytic (asymptotically at least) null distribution? Or knows any literature on similar cases to this?
After reflecting on it more I guess it is basically equivalent to a kind of multiple-testing situation in which we do a separate likelihood ratio test for each two-source assignment case (which should have a simple null distribution, maybe just chi-square with 1 DOF?) and then take the minimum chi-square over all those tests. Should be same result. Not sure if that helps in obtaining the null distribution though, or just illustrates that it is likely not straightforward...
Edit: Hmm I just had the following idea: what if we construct the $P_2$ likelihood like this?
$$
P_2(x_1,...,x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N\mathcal{N}(x_i|\alpha_i\mu_1 + (1-\alpha_i)\mu_2, \Sigma_i)
$$
and maximise over all $\alpha_i \in [0,1]$ (plus $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$). This is a slightly wider family of hypothesis than just two sources, it allows
observations to come from anywhere in a line between the two sources, but the cases we care about are nested in there somewhere and this version should probably better satisfy regularity conditions etc. Will think this over...
Edit: So my idea there does work, null distribution looks pretty nicely chi-square in simulations. Computing the MLE's is a little roundabout, but I decided it's equivalent to finding the best fit straight line to the observations. Need to use a method that accounts for the observation covariances properly, along the lines of Total Least Squares or more generally York Regression (I also saw a paper about "omnivariant generalised least squares" which seemed to describe the most general case in general dimensions). Then the MLEs for the alphas are needed, but they are relatively straightforward to compute by differentiating $logP_2$.
Edit2: Actually I think it only almost works. There is a deficit in the low chi^2 end of the distribution. This almost doesn't matter because the other tail, where we are going to put our test threshold, looks pretty good. I think it happens because I was a little wrong about the nesting, if we allow $\alpha_i \in R$ then the single source hypothesis is not actually nested in the alternate because the alphas always allow fitting anywhere on the infinite best-fit line. But I guess that only matters for datasets that fit the null really well; as soon as there is some indication of separation it doesn't seem to matter too much.

I think this is something clustering people have most likely thought about. I found the following paper for example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947306004920?casa_token=STK3rU5bRBUAAAAA:qhwS7JSSaUsMCVChKdJZTr--OTYLSusLfHiiJ94rk_io9Vt13jaykcOHdnZEprQXayeDFkhiUzk. They consider a similar sort of thing for merging clusters. But they just say something like "it isn't chi-square distributed, but we're going to use chi-square based criteria anyway". But I'm not sure how hard they tried to find alternatives that were chi-square.
